# Correct way to document multiple couses of an error

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard, raise

I am using `yard`to generate documentation for some Ruby classes.

We can document some errors which can be raised by a method like this:

```
# @raise [ArgumentError] Cause 1
# @raise [ArgumentError] Cause 2
# @raise [ArgumentError] Cause 3
# @raise [ArgumentError] ...
# @raise [ArgumentError] Cause n
```

Is this a good way?
Is there another better?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `markdown` markup to designate different cases when the same exception occurs, rather than `yard` internals:

```
# @raise [ArgumentError] may be thrown in different circumstances:
# * Cause 1
# * Cause 2
# * Cause N
```

Yard seems to be confused whether it meets the same “keys” in one document block, which differ by explanation only.